# "I click on SignOut but I don't know if it logs out or not because I stay in the same fragment. What could be the reason?"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

"I click on SignOut but I don't know if it logs out or not because I stay in the same fragment."I want to go to the SignInActivity page when I log out, but it doesn't go and stays in the same fragment. That's my problem." What could be the reason?"

HomePageActivity.kt

class HomePageActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private lateinit var auth : FirebaseAuth
//Bottom Navigation View
val homeFragment = HomeFragment()
val myAccountFragment = MyAccountFragment()
val notificationFragment = NotificationFragment()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page)

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    //Bottom Navigation View
    val bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation)

    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, HomeFragment()).commit()

    bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.home -> {
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, homeFragment)
                    .commit()
                true
            }
            R.id.notification -> {
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, notificationFragment).commit()
                true
            }
            R.id.my_account -> {
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, myAccountFragment).commit()
                true
            }
            else -> false
        }
    }
}
```

}

MyAccountFragment.kt

class MyAccountFragment : Fragment() {

```
private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_account, container, false)

    setHasOptionsMenu(true)

    val toolbar: Toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.my_account_toolbar)

    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.my_account_fragment_menu)

    return view
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_account_fragment_menu, menu)
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    if (item.itemId == R.id.SignOut) {
        auth.signOut()
        val intent = Intent(activity, SignInActivity::class.java)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        startActivity(intent)
        activity?.finish()
        return true
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

}

"I click on SignOut but I don't know if it logs out or not because I stay in the same fragment. What could be the reason?"

Comment: "I don't know if it logs out". Then check it. Debug your code, look if `onOptionsItemSelected` executes and if comes inside the `if` statement. Either by setting breakpoints or simple log statements. But seeing as you stay in the fragment I suspect the function doesn't even execute or you use the wrong id in the `if` statement. Learn how to debug your code

Comment: "I want to go to the SignInActivity page when I log out, but it doesn't go and stays in the same fragment. That's my problem."

Comment: delete the intent and get the activtiy finishing working first. You do `activity.?finish()` which is null safe, so perhaps `activity` is null